# Embedding for $C_{0}(\Omega)$ to $L^{p}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a bounded domain and $f_{1}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be an element of $C_{0}(\Omega)$. Define $C_{0}(\Omega) := \{f\in C(\overline{\Omega})\,|\, f|_{\partial\Omega}=0 \}$. Then, I can immediately see that 
\begin{align*}
||f_{1}||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}&=\bigg(\int_{\Omega}|f_{1}(x)|^{2}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\leq \bigg(\int_{\Omega}(\max_{\overline{\Omega}}|f_{1}|)^{2}dx\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= |\Omega|^{\frac{1}{2}}\max_{\overline{\Omega}}|f_{1}|\\
&= C(\Omega)||f_{1}||_{C_{0}(\Omega)}<\infty
\end{align*}

In fact, I can see that for $1\leq p \leq\infty$, I have $||f_{1}||_{L^{p}(\Omega)} \leq C(\Omega)||f_{1}||_{C_{0}(\Omega)}$.
So, I can at least say that  is embedded $C_{0}(\Omega)$ to $L^{p}(\Omega)$.

Now, my problems are the followings :
 1. How to ensure that the embedding is compact at least for $1<p<\infty$?
 2. We know that $L^{p}$-spaces are spaces for equivalent classes of functions up to zero Lebesgue Measure. So, how to give a precise meaning of the embedding to $L^{p}$ since we have two different objects here.

Any clear explanation is pretty much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: If $\iota : C_0[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$  was compact we could approximate the image of the unit ball by a finite dimensional vector space which is not the case since $\iota(\sin nx)$ cannot be approximated by a linear combination of $\iota(\sin(mx)), m< n$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying question 1. But I still do not understand about question 2.

Comment: When the equivalent class contains a continuous function it is chosen as the canonical representative. It is just saying that in $L^p$ to check if $f=g$ we can't just say $f(x)\ne g(x)$ for some $x$, we need to look at $\|f-g\|$. For the representative : the real number $1.000..$ is preferred to $0.999...$.